# Formally prove that $F_{n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise at $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I have the following function:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{5} \\
5x-1, & \text{if } \frac{1}{5} \leq x < \frac{2}{5} \\
1, & \text{if } \frac{2}{5} \leq x < \frac{3}{5} \\
-5x+4, & \text{if } \frac{3}{5} \leq x < \frac{4}{5} \\
0, & \text{if } \frac{4}{5} \leq x \leq  1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

and define $ a_{0} = \int_{0}^{1}  \! f(x) \, dx ,  a_{k}= 2 \int_{0}^{1}  \! f(x) \cos(2kx\pi)\, dx, , 
  b_{k}= 2 \int_{0}^{1}  \! f(t)\sin(2kx\pi)\, dx  $

Consider the series of functions in [0, 1] whose sequence of partial sums $\{F_n\}$ is defined by

\begin{equation}
    F_{n}= a_{0} + \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{k}cos(2kx\pi) + b_{k}\sin(2kx\pi))
\end{equation}

Formally prove that $F_{n} \rightarrow f$ punctually in $[0,1]$.

I calculate the values of $a_{0}$, $a_{k}$ and $b_{k}$  which are given by
\begin{align*}
a_{0} &= \int_{0}^{1} f(t) ,dt \\
&= \frac{4}{10}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a_{k} &= 2\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \cos(2kx\pi) dx \\
&=\frac{5}{2{\pi}^2}\left[ \dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{4{\pi}k}{5}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{2{\pi}k}{5}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{8{\pi}k}{5}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{6{\pi}k}{5}\right)}{k^2}\right]
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
b_{k} &= 2\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin(2kx\pi) dx \\
&=\frac{5}{2{\pi}^2}\left[ \dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{4{\pi}k}{5}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{2{\pi}k}{5}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{8{\pi}k}{5}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{6{\pi}k}{5}\right)}{k^2}\right]  \
\end{align*}

my idea is to use dirichlet's theorem for Fourier series, for which I make a substitution of the form S=$2\pi x-\pi$ since the theorem states that it must be piecewise continuous in $[-\pi,\pi]$ but then making this substitution I am left with $a_{k}$ and $b_{k}$

$a_{k}= 2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \! f(\frac{s+\pi}{2\pi}) \cos(ks)\, ds$

$b_{k}= 2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \! f(\frac{s+\pi}{2\pi}) \sin(ks)\, ds$

I already have all the hypotheses of the theorem, but I don't know how to conclude to say that the function converges point-wise obviously also changing $a_{0}$

Is this correct? what can I do better? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you mean *pointwise*?

Comment: yes, is pointwise